# To include rich text area in XSLT page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xslt, rich-text-editor

In one of the legacy project, business want to have rich text area on the client page. 
The page is based on XSLT and javascript.

The knowledge that I am having  about xsl/xslt is limited. I searched on internet but not able to find any helpful/complete answer to my question.

**Need to know whether we can support rich text editor in XSL/XSLT page.**

Answer (score 0):

The traditional approach to using XSLT on the browser is that XSLT simply generates the HTML page content. So you have to think about how to do the rich text editing in HTML/Javascript, and then when you've worked out what HTML and Javascript you want, it's a fairly simple job to write the XSLT code to generate it.

If you want to code more of the actual interactive behaviour in XSLT, then you could consider using Saxon-JS. As well as supporting XSLT 3.0 rather than the rather ancient 1.0 standard supported natively by the browsers, it allows you to write XSLT code that actually responds to user input events, rather than having to write this in Javascript. Declaration of interest: Saxon-JS is my product.